# Properly written init method within module action

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

From Nuxt.js [website](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action) we get example for async nuxtServerInit method:

```
actions: {
  async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }) {
    await dispatch('core/load')
  }
}
```

In my case I have modules and this is the way I use them:

```
import state from './state'
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as mutations from './mutations'
import * as getters from './getters'

import messages from './modules/messages'
import notifications from './modules/notifications'

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
  modules: {
    messages,
    notifications
  }
}
```

Inside base actions I have:

```
export default function nuxtServerInit ({ commit, getters }, { req, res }) {}
```

This works unless I add axios call in. How can I properly add async/await to this kind of exporting function. There is no examples for this anywhere on the website....

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is use `async/await` with axios in `nuxtServerInit`:

```
export default function nuxtServerInit ({ commit, dispatch }, { req, res }) {
  try {
    await dispatch('core/load')     
  } catch (err) {

  }
}
```

And in your module:

```
async load() {
  return await this.$axios....
}
```

Comment: I just came up with different approach that is working, you can tell me if it is right one:

`export async function nuxtServerInit ({ commit, getters }, { req, res }) { await axios .... }`